# MongoDB, displaying two finds in a single line

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to display the results from two mongodb queries:

```
db.games.aggregate([{$match:{player_id:12345}},{"$group" : {_id:"$player_id", count:{$sum:1}}}])`
db.games.aggregate([{$match:{player_id:6789}},{"$group" : {_id:"$player_id", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Each query will find the number of games each player has played in, but I need to compare the number of games between the two in a single query.

The output would be similar to:

`{"PlayerA":37,"PlayerB":98}`

Answer (score 0):

The `$match` aggregation query operator determines which documents will be found from the database, and can use all of the normal mongo search query operators. Your `$group` is already correctly summing by `$player_id`, so you can update your `$match` to include both ids, and your pipeline should work:

`db.games.aggregate([{$match:{player_id: {$in: [12345, 6789]}},{"$group" : {_id:"$player_id", count:{$sum:1}}}])`